# Only reverse the direction of consecutive Hebrew words in a string including non-Hebrew characters

Tags: php, string, reverse, hebrew, multibyte

I am trying to reverse a string  containing Hebrew from RTL to LTR, but my coding attempt is reversing brackets as well. `strrev()` didn't work because it does not  actually work for UTF8 strings. So I wrote a custom function,  below is my code:

```
$str = 'תירס גדול A-10 (פרי גליל)';
function utf8_strrev($str)
{
    $arr = '';
    $words = explode(" ", $str);
    $start_tag = '(';
    $end_tag = ')';
    foreach ($words as $word)
    {
        if (preg_match("/\p{Hebrew}/u", $word))
        {
                preg_match_all('/./us', $word, $ar);
                echo print_r($ar[0]);
                echo '<br>';
                
                $arr = join('', array_reverse($ar[0])) . " " . $arr;
        } else
        {
            preg_match_all('/./us', $word, $ar);
            $arr = join('', $ar[0]) . " " . $arr;
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
)לילג ירפ( A-10 לודג סרית
```

what it should be:

```
(לילג ירפ) A-10 לודג סרית
```

Comment: Ehm, try this: [PHP: strrev](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) there is a function for what you want :)

Comment: [Is Google broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434250/how-to-reverse-a-unicode-string)

Comment: Its does not work for UTF8 string actually.

Comment: Why dont you add that to your question, you knew people where going to answer that.

Comment: its think some reg expression expert can solve this i am not good with req expressions

Comment: is it always brackets? just use `str_replace` at the end

Comment: It's still somewhat unclear if you want to reverse the whole string, just each word, or why you look for parens specifically and loop over things.

Comment: You don't want to reverse your string - you want to change it from RTL to LTR - this could work: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hebrev.php

Comment: @stuXnet never link to that site, link to the manual

Comment: reverse is not doing job as well out put is (תירס גדול A-10 (פרי גליל

Comment: @mario my only requirement is RTL to LTR but this string is creating issue. Any suggestion to to reverse it as it cannot be reversed with simple string strrev.?

Comment: @AzharMuhammad, you are close, so just use str_replace, at the end, as Dagon suggested...

Comment: str_replace is not good way it can be {} or [] as well so i want some generalize sol.

Answer (score 2):

Found this function in the comments on the docs that KoenHoeijmakers posted. I tested it, but I don't read Hebrew so it is hard for me to tell if it's working correctly.

```
function utf8_strrev($str){
    preg_match_all('/./us', $str, $ar);
    return join('',array_reverse($ar[0]));
}
```

### Edit

Based on reading your question again, I *think* this works as you need it to?

```
function utf8_strrev($str)
{

    $arr = '';
    $words = explode(" ", $str);
    $start_tag = '(';
    $end_tag = ')';
    foreach ($words as $word)
    {
        if (preg_match("/\p{Hebrew}/u", $word))
        {
                preg_match_all('/./us', $word, $ar);
                $arr = join('', array_reverse($ar[0])) . " " . $arr;
        } else
        {
            preg_match_all('/./us', $word, $ar);
            $arr = join('', $ar[0]) . " " . $arr;
        }
    }

    return preg_replace(array('/\)(.)/','/(.)\(/','/\}(.)/','/(.)\{/'),array('($1','$1)','{$1','$1}'),$arr);
}
$str='תירס גדול A-10 {פרי גליל}';

echo utf8_strrev($str);
```

#### Outut

```
{לילג ירפ} A-10 לודג סרית
```

Again, I don't read Hebrew, but hopefully it answers your question.

**Note** The reason I used `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace` is because the string replace method was giving me issues text like `( somthing something (` or `) something something )`

Comment: @AzharMuhammad made an edit, let me know if it works.

Comment: I'll have to see if it still gets reversed and if so I'll edit it when I get to my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak/read Hebrew, but this seems to work as desired.

I generally dislike nesting `preg_` calls inside `preg_` calls, but in this case, splitting the unicode characters into an array then reversing the elements prevents the need to bother with mb_encodings.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/usfi2))

```
$str = 'תירס גדול A-10 (פרי גליל)';
echo preg_replace_callback(
         "/\p{Hebrew}+(?: \p{Hebrew}+)*/u",
         fn($m) => implode(
             array_reverse(
                 preg_split('~~u', $m[0], 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
             )
         ),
         $str
     );
```

Output:

```
סרית A-10 (לילג ירפ)
```

The `preg_replace_callback()` pattern isolates consecutive space-delimited Hebrew words, then the anonymous function splits the multibyte letters into individual array elements, before reversing their order and joining the elements back into a single mutated string.

Comment: A somewhat related question: [Reverse "English" words in a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53516119/2943403)