# Reverse "English" words in a sentence

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have string in which there might multiple languages being used, for example:

```
این متن فارسی است and this is !!! in English
این خط بعدی است و this is going to be continued...
```

I want only to reverse words in English, so the outcome should be smth like:

```
این متن فارسی است English in !!! is this and
این خط بعدی است و continued be to going is this...
```

For the text to be reversed, I got:

```
public static function reverseEnglishWords($string)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('/\w+/', function (array $m) { return strrev($m[0]); }, $string);
}
```

but it reverses all the characters.

---

EDIT:
this is what working best right now:

```
<?php
$string = "
این یک تست جدید است
Is my English line working just fine?
I hope it does...
این یک جمله جدید است and this is to be continued in English...
";

$newStr = preg_replace_callback('/\w.*(?=\w|\b)/', function (array $m) { 
    return implode(" ", array_reverse(explode(" ", $m[0])));
}, $string);

echo $newStr;
```

The only problem with this is some characters in the enf of the string, like `?` and `...` which is misplaced in the example above. current outcome is:

`این یک تست جدید است
fine just working line English my Is?
does it hope I...
این یک جمله جدید است English in continued be to is this and...`

**which should be:**

`این یک تست جدید است
?fine just working line English my Is
...does it hope I
این یک جمله جدید است ...English in continued be to is this and`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's the problem actually, I can reverse chars only not the words in a sentence :(

Comment: Then, do you only have spaces between English words?  Those you want to reverse?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, no, there might be any chars like `!`.

Comment: Please add another example string with expected output to showcase this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew updated the question

Comment: are there non-English words in the middle of English words?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew then it should not be considered as the same sentence anymore, that's a new sentence. so the answer is No

Comment: Try `return preg_replace_callback('/\P{Arabic}+/u', function ($m) { 
           return " " . implode(" ", array_reverse(preg_split('~\s+~u', $m[0], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)));
        }, $string);`, see https://3v4l.org/pGeJX

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's working, make it an answer so I can accept it. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
function reverseEnglishWords($string)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('/(?!\s)[^\p{Arabic}\r\n]+/u', function ($m) { 
            $tmp = preg_replace_callback('~(\w+)([^\w\s]+)~', function($n) {
                return strrev($n[2]) . $n[1];
            }, $m[0]);
            return implode(" ", array_reverse(
                    preg_split('~\s+~u', $tmp, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
                  )
            );
        }, $string);
}

$s = "
این یک تست جدید است
Is my English line working just fine?
I hope it does...
Another one?!
این یک جمله جدید است and this is to be continued in English...
";

echo reverseEnglishWords($s);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/t9THR), output

```
این یک تست جدید است
?fine just working line English my Is
...does it hope I
!?one Another
این یک جمله جدید است ...English in continued be to is this and
```

Here, [`/(?!\s)[^\p{Arabic}\r\n]+/u`](https://regex101.com/r/uSwhTG/2/) matches one or more consecutive chars (starting with a non-whitespace char) that do not belong to the Arabic script and that are not CR and LF. The matches are passed to the `preg_replace_callback` anonymous function where the match is first processed with another `preg_replace_callback` to reverse letters and punctuation in words that start with letters and end with punctuation (see [`(\w+)([^\w\s]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/vKXO7d/1) regex) and then split with any kind of Unicode whitespace while discarding empty items (see `preg_split('~\s+~u', $m[0], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)`), `array_reverse` reverses the array of "words" found, and `implode` joins the reversed items with a space.

Comment: it seems it's messing the line breaks and also some character positions like `?`

Comment: @behz4d So, the line breaks should be excluded? You only want the pattern to work only line by line? What do you mean by character positions?

Comment: see this demo, it is working just fine just some problems with special characters in the end of the string: https://3v4l.org/ARscb

Comment: updated my question with the new example in the end.

Comment: @behz4d Wait, the punctuation and symbols must be thus separated from the letter words, right?

Comment: The rule is when you read the English sentence from `Right to Left`, it must make sense and sounds well, like this: `?name your is what`

Comment: @behz4d That is not straight-forward. You want to match the trailing punctuation symbols glued to words on the right and move them in the reversed order to the left of these words, right? So that `word?!` turned out `!?word`?

Comment: Yes exactly that is what I want.

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME!

Comment: One last thing, can this ignore URLs? so nothing should happen to URLs and links starting with `www.`, `http` and ...

Comment: @behz4d Try `'~\b(?:(?:ht|f)tps?://|www\.)\S*(*SKIP)(*F)|(\w+)([^\w\s]+)~'` regex with the nested `preg_replace_callback`. See [this demo](https://3v4l.org/YDjrk). Not sure if it is what you expect, you will need to think about punctuation after URLs, which symbols should go before it and which to keep on the right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184401/discussion-between-behz4d-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1):

Use array reverse

```
$str = 'what is you doin';
$str = explode(' ', $str);
$str = array_reverse($str);
echo implode(' ', $str);
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the string of English words should first be identified with regex.

Comment: this reverses all the words in a string.

Comment: my bad. still trying out solutions. I thought you translated the words on the side lmao, didn't notice it was part of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select string that start with english character and end with english character. Then in callback function split string by space and reverse array using `array_reverse()`

```
$newStr = preg_replace_callback('/\w.*(?=\w|\b)/', function (array $m) { 
    return implode(" ", array_reverse(explode(" ", $m[0])));
}, $string);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/Ih7Ec)

Comment: `.*` will match all chars other than line break chars, and it will match all Arabic script chars if they happen in between other chars, and will get reversed, too.

Comment: this answer works best, but still some issues with some characters like `?` and also `...` in the end of the string, see this: https://3v4l.org/ARscb

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

function reverseSentence($string)
{
    $array = explode(" ", $string);
    $rarray = array_reverse($array);
    $reversed = implode(" ", $rarray);
    return $reversed;
}

function reverseEnglishWords($string)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('/[\s\w\d]*/', function($m) {
        return reverseSentence($m[0]);
    } , $string);
}

$s = "این متن فارسی است and this is !!! in English";
echo reverseEnglishWords($s);
```

output:

```
> $ php example.php
این متن فارسی است is this and !!!English in
```